# What is wrong with my data contract?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

Ok, this is my RIA Services data contract:

```
public class ZipLocationDC
{
    [Key]
    public String ZipCode { get; set; }

    [Editable(false)]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    [Editable(false)]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

I have hundreds other entities very similar to this (i.e. simple classes with little more than primitive-typed properties).  With this one for some reason, I get the following exception:

> Operation named 'GetZipLocation' does not conform to the required
>   signature. Return types must be an entity or complex type, a
>   collection of entities or complex types, or one of the predefined
>   serializable types.

What am I doing wrong?  I don't know why you would need it, but here is my service operation:

```
    [Invoke]
    public ZipLocationDC GetZipLocation(String a_strZipCode)
    {
        var zipCodes = from zipCode in ObjectContext.ZipCodes
                       where zipCode.Code == a_strZipCode
                       select zipCode;

        if (!zipCodes.Any())
            return null;

        var dLatitude = zipCodes.Average(i => i.Latitude);
        var dLongitude = zipCodes.Average(i => i.Longitude);

        return new ZipLocationDC
            {
                ZipCode = a_strZipCode,
                Latitude = dLatitude,
                Longitude = dLongitude
            };
    }
```

I'm seriously getting tired with RIA Services.  I also use straight up WCF, but with RIA I get strange problems like this all the time.  Its almost not worth using it.

Comment: RIA voodoo is driving me nuts too.

Answer (score 2):

This is so dumb and why I am switching over to WCF as soon as I can.  I had to include my data contract (`ZipLocationDC`) as the result of a query operation.  I just return null. I added this code to my service definition.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method does nothing but expose ZipLocationDC as an read-only entity.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Null.</returns>
    [Query]
    public IQueryable<ZipLocationDC> GetZipLocations()
    {
        return null;
    }
```

RIA Services is so painfully limiting.  I know it does stuff for you, but its been more of a problem than a helper.

Comment: Gaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa!! I just hit this today.  I hate RiaServices.  Thanks for posting a reply.

Comment: I recommend WCF. It doesn't hold your hand, but you don't get any of these dumb surprises either.

Comment: I've been doing WCF since 2005. "Exactly!" (to your sentiments). I'm skeptical of all Microsoft Auto-Magic-Voodoo now. This time it is Ria Services

Comment: Well, no some of it will work OK. Assure stuff works really well, for instance. It just depends.